# Harvesting information from the Internet asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a WPF application which presents a list of items. I would like to show an icon in UI if certain information exists on a web server for a given item (I need to download HTML web-page and verify its content to decide if the icon should be shown or not).

The number of items may be quite big (more than 100), so requesting a web server synchronously may freeze the application for a longer time. I would like to do it asynchronously and update the UI after retrieving each piece of information. What is the best way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the work. Update the UI in the `ProgressChanged` event handler

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    int count = urlsToCheck.Count;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        bool urlValid = CheckUrl(url);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 * (i + 1) / count, new CheckUrlResult(url, urlValid));
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckUrlResult result = e.UserState as CheckUrlResult;
    textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0} : {1}\n", result.Url, result.IsValid);
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea.

Should there be a single BackgroundWorker? I am asking because I think it may be faster to get the results by having more than a single request to the web server at the same time.

Comment: You can add a lot of BW in your app.
Just think about to check their state (IsBusy) and check if form is not disable when you are on finished event.

Comment: Does each BW uses a new thread? I wonder because adding a BW per item may damage the performance if too many threads will be created.

Comment: Yes, each BW uses a new thread. You could use multiple BWs, you just need to handle a queue of requests to process and dispatch them to the next available BW. Another option would be to use the ThreadPool class, however it's a bit harder to use, because you have to execute the code that accesses the UI on the UI thread, using invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Using Backgroundworkers is a good way to solve your problem
It's easy to use : 
You run an asyn operation without freeze your app and you are notified when operation asyn is done.

Some exemple here : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx
http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/252416-C-and-WPF-progressbar/

MSDN definition of BW :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx

hope this help.